# Including text with padding in the selection block

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection, opacity

I have text with padding and opacity, but when the user selects it, it appears with ***spaces*** and a ***different selection color***.  `.main` and `.start` are necessary for my code. How do I fix this?

```css
  .main {
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
  .start {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

```html
    <span class="main">
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
    </span>
    <span class="start">13941</span>
    <span class="main">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
    </span>
```

[image]

Comment: Its not spaces, it is padding.  You cant have it both way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a blank space in each `.paragraph` using JS, and set the opacity to color `#C1C1C1`.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to remove the padding from the `.main` class. Rather than make the text opaque, I took the color of the text created by the opacity and made the text color that color. That allows the selection color to remain consistent.

I've also changed the selection color back to the browser's standard blue color. If you do that, then everything works as expected.

```
.main {
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```css
.main span {
  color: #C1C1C1;
  
  &::selection {
    background-color: #3291FF;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="main">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem</span>
<span class="start">13941</span>
<span class="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
```

Comment: But i need the main class ... And it doesn't solve the problem of selection opacity.

Comment: If you leave the padding on there, then, your problem will remain.

Comment: Maybe there is another solution ...  I tried :after and :before with empty space as content, but the problem is the same.

Comment: I've updated my answer. You've changed the opacity of the span tag. That comes with some consequences.

Comment: When you select the span tag, it's not a **different selection color** as you noted... it's the same color, but with opacity applied.

Comment: Text selection should be consistent, with no opacity and gaps. Any idea how to achieve this? With gaps, I think I could add a blank space in each `.paragraph` using JS, and with opacity, I think I could handle it with different font-weight.

Comment: I updated my answer again. I left the standard browser's selection color as blue. If you do that, then you get what you're looking for.